# ASP.NET AutoPostBack for SelectedIndexChanged fires form's onsubmit script

Tags: asp.net, onsubmit, autopostback, selectedindexchanged

Since upgrading from .NET 1.1 to 4.0 I have a problem with a form.

The form has some dropdowns with AutoPostBack=true because they have some SelectedIndexChanged handlers that need to fire to populate other dropdowns, etc.

But now, when a new value is selected in the dropdown, it fires the onSubmit script specified in the form tag:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" onsubmit="return jvsValidate() ;">
```

Where before, that would only fire when the button control was clicked:

```
<asp:button id="btnRoute" runat="server" text="Save"></asp:button>
```

What's the best way to rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove from onsubmit="return jvsValidate() ;" in form tag and update syntax with button like below

```
<asp:button id="btnRoute" runat="server" text="Save" OnClientClick="return jvsValidate();" ></asp:button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the easiest workaround would be to attach `jvsValidate()` to the `btnRoute` click event, rather than the form's submit event.  Just add some Javascript to the effect `document.getElementById('btnRoute').click = jsValidate;`, and remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the form.